# Installing specific versions of pyproj from github

Tags: pip, cython

I have been trying to install obspy and have been running into a lot of problems. I want to install [obspy](https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki) which has a dependency on [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/). But apparently obspy only works with pyproj 1.9.5.1, which I tried installing using pip (`pip3 install pyproj==1.9.5.1`), but only got the errors like-

```
_proj.c:7488:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
```

Digging deeper I found that it might be a Cython problem, and installing pyproj directly from github might help, because it would apparently make Cython recompile all the necessary files. Something along the lines of -

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj.git
```

However this one gives the error -

```
ERROR: Minimum supported proj version is 6.2.0, installed version is 5.2.0.
```

I di try installing a higher version of `libproj-dev` (`sudo apt install libproj-dev=6.2.0`) however it shows that there is no candidate for 6.2.0. I tried downloading the [deb file](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libproj-dev/download) and installing from that using -

```
sudo apt-get install ~/Downloads/libproj-dev_6.2.0-1_amd64.deb
```

which just leads to the error -

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libproj-dev : Depends: libproj15 (= 6.2.0-1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But I think this is not the right way to install for me anyway, since I need a specific version. Hence I tried installing directly from the tarball of the release -

```
pip3 install https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/archive/v1.9.5.1rel.tar.gz
```

Which leads to the first error I had, evidently due to Cython.

With errors on everything I tried to do to fix this, I am not sure what even is relevant to my problem now.

Any help is appreciated, and if this site is not the correct place for this question, please help me migrate it to its proper destination.

I am on Ubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that Cython-generated c-files [don't work for Python-3.7](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1955) if generated with Cython versions up to 0.27.3 (at least): The `setup.py` of pyproj (at least in the version 1.9.5.1) doesn't regenerate the`_proj.c`, which is generated with Cython 0.23.2 and thus the installation cannot succeed.

You have the following options:

- stay on Python3.6 where everything works out of the box.
- regenerate `_proj.c` with a current Cython-version.

For the second option:

1. download and unzip your prefered version from https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/releases/tag/v1.9.5.1rel and switch to the created folder `pyproj-1.9.5.1rel`.
2. check, that the cython-version is `>=0.27.3.` via `cython --version`.
3. regenerate the `_proj.c` file via `cython -3 _proj.pyx` (`_proj.pyx` looks like Python3-code, but also `language_level=2` (i.e.  `cython -2 _proj.pyx`) will probably work.
4. install running `pip install .`

Comment: I went with the second option because that's kinda what I was trying to figure out. I just did not know how to generate the _proj.c file using cython. I did not even know that that was the problem I had. So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[pyproj 1.9.5.1](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/1.9.5.1/#files) was release at Jan 7, 2016. At that time, the latest version Python was 3.5. In my tests. pyproj 1.9.5.1 failed to be installed on Python 3.7.4, but succeeded on Python 3.5.7.

You need to create a environment with **Python 3.5** by [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) or [conda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/).

References

- [pyproj 1.9.5.1 release](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/1.9.5.1/#files)
- [Python release history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_release_dates)